# TIBCO API Exchange Gateway Integration - External/Public API availability

Tags: tibco

Does TIBCO API Exchange Gateway expose external/public APIs (or an SDK) for integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a config API that is available in the following directory :
<TIBCO_HOME>\asg\2.4\examples\ConfigAPI

This allows you to export and reimport some parts of the configuration in JSON format.